# What would be the PHP 'REGEX' expression to not have '.' or a 'space'

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to build a user creation form, and I dont want the username to have a 'fullstop' or 'space' or any special characters.

What would be the REGEX expression to do this?

Only Alpha numeric allowed.

Is this correct : "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"

Thank you.

Comment: Are you ONLY wanting an alphanumeric input? Or are some 'special' characters allowed?

Comment: @JustinWood +1 for this question .. !

Comment: Only alpha numeric allowed.

Comment: You can use: `^[0-9A-Za-z]+$`

Comment: Your question is extremely vague (e.g. what is a "special character" and why does "space" fall into that same category?). Also, here at SO, you're supposed to do some research first and provide the community with what you tried and didn't work for you.

Comment: @ClassStacker I did.. See the question above.. My REGEX just did not work

Comment: This is correct, but allowing and the _ special character.

Comment: You said only alphanumeric, but your REGEX matches on `_`, is that something you want?

Comment: If you got any answer please upvote ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[a-z0-9]+$/i`

if you wanted to match on alphanumeric AND `_`, just simply use `/^\w+$/i`

the `i` at the end means case insensitive, meaning you can have both `a` and `A`
the `$` means end of line, and the `^` means beginning of line.

Use those to match the ENTIRE input, else you could just match on a partial and get a false positive.

This solution will allow for a minimum of 1 character. If you wanted a minimum of say 5 characters, change the `+` to `{5,}`.

If you wanted between 5 and 10 characters, replace it with `{5,10}` or whatever the actual values you want.

Comment: This will match an empty string. `var_dump((bool) preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]*$/i', '') );`.

Answer (score 1):

Allows only alphanumeric:

```
/^[a-z0-9]{2,}$/i
```

- `/` - Delimiter
- `^` - Start of the string
- `[]` - Character class
- `{2,}` - Two more more of the previous character allowed. Add a number after the comma to add a maximum number of characters.
- `$` - End of the string
- `/` - Delimiter
- `i` - Case-insensitive

[Regex101 Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/wA2bE4)

Comment: `\w` also matches on `_` which is not wanted here.

Comment: "* - One or more" -- Umm, no.

Comment: Thank you both - I hadn't had my coffee yet this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(preg_match('^/[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/' $_POST['username'])
{
    // Do stuff
}
else
{
    // Do error
}
```

This will match any string that start and ends with any character between a-z, A-Z and 0-9.

Based on the later update of your Question the code should be like that:

```
if(preg_match('^/[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$/' $_POST['username'])
{
    // Do stuff
}
else
{
    // Do error
}
```

Comment: This will not match for the numeric characters

Comment: @JustinWood, I didn't see the alpha numeric, I just read alpha :)

Comment: If you are matching on alphanumeric AND `_`, just use `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('/(.*?)\.(.*?)/is', $string) || preg_match('/(.*?)\d(.*?)/is', $string)){
   return false;
}
```